# How to initialize an array inside a struct GLSL

Tags: glsl, shader

I'm try to initialize an array inside a struct, as follow:

```
struct myStruct {

  vec3 data[20] = vec3[20] (vec3(1, 1,  1), vec3( 1, -1,  1), vec3(-1, -1,  1), vec3(-1, 1,  1),
                            vec3(1, 1, -1), vec3( 1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, 1, -1),
                            vec3(1, 1,  0), vec3( 1, -1,  0), vec3(-1, -1,  0), vec3(-1, 1,  0),
                            vec3(1, 0,  1), vec3(-1,  0,  1), vec3( 1,  0, -1), vec3(-1, 0, -1),
                            vec3(0, 1,  1), vec3( 0, -1,  1), vec3( 0, -1, -1), vec3( 0, 1, -1));

};
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: 0:84: '=' : syntax error: syntax error
```

It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`struct` starts a type specification and not a variable declaration. You have to declare a variable and to use a struct constructor (See [Data Type (GLSL) - Struct constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Struct_constructors)):

```
struct myStruct {
    vec3 data[20];
};

myStruct myVar = myStruct( vec3[20]( vec3(1, 1,  1), ..... ) );
```

See [GLSL Specification - 4.1.8 Structures](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> User-defined types can be created by aggregating other already defined types into a structure using the **struct** keyword. For example,
>
> ```
> struct keyword. For example,
>     struct light {
>     float intensity;
>     vec3 position;
> } lightVar;
> ```
>
> Structures can be initialized at declaration time using constructors, as discussed in section 5.4.3 “Structure
>   Constructors”

See [GLSL Specification - 5.4.3 Structure Constructors](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> Once a structure is defined, and its type is given a name, a constructor is available with the same name to
>   construct instances of that structure. For example:
>
> ```
> struct light {
>     float intensity;
>     vec3 position;
> };
> light lightVar = light(3.0, vec3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
> ```